# Rspec fails to load support files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I cannot get rspec to load support files, have tried:

```
config.include SessionHelper, :type => :controller
```

In the spec_helper file, Which gives me

```
NameError: uninitialized constant SessionsSpecHelper
```

Adding:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

Gives me:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
```

Adding:

```
require 'support/session_helpers.rb'
```

Provides no difference

support/session_helper.rb:

```
module SessionHelpers
def sign_up_with(email, password)
  visit sign_up_path
  fill_in 'Email', with: email
  fill_in 'Password', with: password
  click_button 'Sign up'
end

def sign_in
  user = create(:user)
  visit sign_in_path
  fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
  fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
  click_button 'Sign in'
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noticed the error `config.include SessionsHelper, :type => :controller`

has Sessions

while your module `module SessionHelpers` has Session

Comment: Good call, I just noticed the typo